# передача значения переменной между классами swift

Tags: swift, классы, переменные

У меня два *.swift файла в проекте. В первом ViewController - отображается слайдер.

Во втором  - Drawer  - отрисовывается линия. При этом координата X -  это значение переменной слайдера.

Мега задача -  это изменение координат линии (перерисовка) при движении слайдера.

Как это лучше сделать? Глобальные переменные не предлагать)

это ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

@IBAction func slider(_ sender: UISlider) {
    label.text = String (sender.value) 
    position = Int(sender.value) //тут получаем значение

}
```

А это Drawer

```
import UIKit

//где-то тут надо получить значение position 


class drawer: UIView {

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    context?.setLineWidth(2.0)
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let components: [CGFloat] = [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]
    let color = CGColor(colorSpace: colorSpace, components: components)
    context?.setStrokeColor(color!)
    context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: 30, y: 30))
    context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: position, y: 400))
    context?.strokePath()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    private let drawer: DrawerProtocol = Drawer()

    @IBAction func slider(_ sender: UISlider) {
        label.text = String (sender.value)
        let position = Int(sender.value) //тут получаем значение
        drawer.setPosition(position)
    }

}



import UIKit

//где-то тут надо получить значение position

class Drawer: UIView, DrawerProtocol {

    private var position: Int = 0

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context?.setLineWidth(2.0)
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let components: [CGFloat] = [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]
        let color = CGColor(colorSpace: colorSpace, components: components)
        context?.setStrokeColor(color!)
        context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: 30, y: 30))
        context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: position, y: 400))
        context?.strokePath()
    }

    func changePosition(_ position: Int) {
        self.position = position
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

}

protocol DrawerProtocol {
    func changePosition(_ position: Int)
}
```

---

Вариант 2:

import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    private var position: Int = 0 {
        didSet{
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("positionChanged"), object: nil, userInfo: ["position": position])
        }
    }

    @IBAction func slider(_ sender: UISlider) {
        label.text = String (sender.value)
        self.position = Int(sender.value) //тут получаем значение
    }

}


import UIKit

//где-то тут надо получить значение position

class Drawer: UIView {

    private var position: Int = 0

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(setPosition(_:)), name: Notification.Name("positionChanged"), object: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context?.setLineWidth(2.0)
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let components: [CGFloat] = [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]
        let color = CGColor(colorSpace: colorSpace, components: components)
        context?.setStrokeColor(color!)
        context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: 30, y: 30))
        context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: position, y: 400))
        context?.strokePath()
    }

    @objc func setPosition(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let position = notification.userInfo?["position"] as? Int {
            self.position = position
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

}
```

---

P.S. Не ручаюсь что второй вариант без багов, но главное это сама идея. В первом варианте класс ViewController знает про класс Drawer. во втором нет